# How can I build a linq query at runtime with multiple group by clauses with different types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm in a situation where I need to specify queries on a EF-context at runtime. Our consultants configure these queries at a customer site for customer specific situations.

In order to facilitate that I was thinking of using linq to build the queries, based on a criteria-list which the consultants specify in a front-end of some kind (right now, winforms). The consultants basically specify a property from an object, specify the operator and then the value. For example: give me all clients where the [status] [equals] [1].

At the moment I have an expression builder which creates the where clause at runtime, and so far I can manage one group by clause. Where I'm running against the wall here, is when a consultant configures multiple group by clauses of different types (f.e. a string and a datetime property).

For example, I must be able to process this query: select bsn as a, dateofbirth as b from clients where status = 1 group by bsn, dateofbirth (where bsn = string and dateofbirth = datetime).

At the moment, this is the code which "glues" the query together:

```
public List<ClientV2> ExportClients(List<CriteriaV2> criteriaList)
{
    var whereExpression = BuildWhereExpressionChain(criteriaList.Where(c => c.Operator != CriteriaOperatorV2.GROUPBY).ToList());

    var groupByExpression = BuildGroupByExpression(criteriaList.Where(c => c.Operator == CriteriaOperatorV2.GROUPBY).ToList());

    var sourceClients = _context.Clients.Where(whereExpression).GroupBy(groupByExpression).ToList();

    IEnumerable<Client> resultClients = sourceClients.SelectMany(group => group);

    return ClientToClientV2.MapList(resultClients.ToList());
}
```

This is the where-clause builder:

```
private Expression<Func<Client, bool>> BuildWhereExpressionChain(List<CriteriaV2> criteriaList)
{
    var expressionList = new List<Expression<Func<Client, bool>>>();
    var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Client));

    foreach (var crit in criteriaList)
    {
        var propertyItem = PropertyTranslator.GetPropertyItem(crit.Property);
        if (propertyItem == null) throw new InvalidFilterCriteriaException("Property " + crit.Property + " niet toegestaan als filter criterium");

        var propInfo = typeof(Client).GetProperty(propertyItem.InternalName);
        var left = Expression.Property(paramExp, propInfo);
        Expression right;

        if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
            right = Expression.Constant(Enum.ToObject(propInfo.PropertyType, PropertyTranslator.TranslateEnum(propertyItem.Type, crit.Value)));
        else if (propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            right = Expression.Constant(DateTime.Parse(crit.Value), propInfo.PropertyType);
        else
            right = Expression.Constant(crit.Value, typeof(string));

        var exp = BuildExpression(left, right, crit.Operator);

        expressionList.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<Client, bool>>(exp, new ParameterExpression[] { paramExp }));
    }

    var firstExpression = expressionList.First();
    expressionList.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(ex => { firstExpression = firstExpression.And(ex); });

    return firstExpression;
}
```

And this is the part where I am stuck (it does work for one clause of type string):

```
private Expression<Func<Client, string>> BuildGroupByExpression(List<CriteriaV2> criteriaList)
{
    var expressionList = new List<Expression<Func<Client, string>>>();
    var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Client));

    foreach (var crit in criteriaList)
    {
        var propertyItem = PropertyTranslator.GetPropertyItem(crit.Property);
        if (propertyItem == null) throw new InvalidFilterCriteriaException("Property " + crit.Property + " niet toegestaan als group by criterium");

        var propInfo = typeof(Client).GetProperty(propertyItem.InternalName);
        var body = Expression.Property(paramExp, propInfo);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Client, string>>(body, paramExp);
        expressionList.Add(lambda);
    }

    var firstExpression = expressionList.First();
    expressionList.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(ex => { firstExpression = firstExpression.And(ex); });

    return firstExpression;
}
```

Would it be possible to make the BuildGroupByExpression() in such way that it results in an expression which contains multiple clauses of different types that I can use directly in .GroupBy(expression);?

I'm not that much of an expert on linq, but I have a feeling that what I want could be possible. If I do stupid things here, please point them out and I'll work on it.

Comment: Have you tried dynamiclinq?

Comment: I tried it, but somehow never got it to work, as it appears to not support multiple group by clauses either without writing it myself as well. I did find the documentation lacking tbh, it was just a bunch of .cs files, so maybe I missed something in there.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. At least using the approach where the Expression is built they way you have.  At least I ended up building expressions per type.
The main reason is

```
  var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Client, string>>(body, paramExp);
```

I dont know how you can make this Lambda defintion dynamic or generic.

There is a different approach, and a library that uses a string interpretation at runtime to build expressions. See

```
Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic.Library
```

see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx